# how to allow text attributes to be empty in Yii model?

Tags: validation, yii, model

I have a model for articles, the article can be written in two languages, English and Arabic.

So there are 2 attributes for each language text, I want the both attributes to be allowed to be empty on create and update, knowing that the attributes type are text not varchar.

How i can write a rule for what i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "..knowing that the attributes type are text not varchar..." but Yii has built in mechanism to define your validation rules.

Refer to the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/) for more details.

@hamed pointed out in his answer how to make fields mandatory. You can add to this by specifying the scenarios under which the validation rules are true. For example.

```
array('field1, field2', 'required', 'on' => array('create', 'update'));
```

will apply the 'required' rule only for inserting and updating. On the other hand.

```
array('field1, field2', 'required', 'except' => array('create', 'update'));
```

will apply the 'required' rule only for all scenarios except inserting and updating.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStringValidator

```
array(
   array('text_en','length'),
   array('text_ar','length'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a model from a database table, yii adds something like this inside `rule()` function:

```
array('field1, field2, ...', 'required')
```

This array is based on `NOT NULL` attribute in the database column. It means, if the database field has `NOT NULL` property **checked**, yiis add it in the above array. All you need to do is removing your two fields from above array.